# Find the volume of the set

Tags: integration, volume

I have to find the volume of the set $S=: \lbrace{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: z^2(1+x^2+y^2)^2 \le y^2, x^2+y^2 \le 2x \rbrace}$.
My attempt:
$z \in \left[-\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}}, \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}}\right]$

In a turn, $x^2+y^2\le 2x$ is a circle. I can use polar coordinates.
I have $ \int\int_S 2\sqrt{\frac{r\sin t}{r^2+1}}drdt$

Comment: Apart part polar coordinates, you may use bounty.